# Kazmath error when adding 64 bit support

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, 64-bit

I've updated to Cocos2d v2.2, and added arm64 in my build settings. When i run my project i get this error:
**Lexical or Preprocessor Issue,
 'kazmath/neon_matrix_impl.h" file not found**

Comment: does neon_matrix_impl.h exist somewhere on your hard drive?

Comment: Yes, what do you mean?

Comment: where is that import line found?  In your own code or in Cocos2d code?

Comment: its found in Cocos2d code

Answer (score 1):

Okay, my guess is that your project's header search paths need to be updated.

To do this, go into the project "Build Settings" and type in "header search" to easily look up the header search path setting.  It should look like this:

[Open Build Settings http://www.apusstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Screen-Shot-2014-09-22-at-8.46.14-am-1024x399.png](http://www.apusstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Screen-Shot-2014-09-22-at-8.46.14-am-1024x399.png)

And make sure these two paths are in there:

```
$(SRCROOT)/../cocos2d/cocos/platform/ios
$(SRCROOT)/../cocos2d/cocos/platform/ios/Simulation
```

Comment: just make sure that the folder the "missing" file is in, is included in the header search path. You can use an absolute path but if the file (and thus cocos2d) is not under SRCROOT you should fix that first.